# Gitlab merge request includes commits from target branch

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

Gitlab merge requests are picking up and including commits merged into target branch. How do I avoid this?

`feature` branch is created off of `master`. `feature` commits `A`, `B`, `C` while `master` commits `D`, `E`. `feature` branch's Merge Request targets `master`. The Merge Request on gitlab now includes `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`.

I've tried "Fast-forward merge" in settings. Not sure how to avoid this as it's happening on all my Merge Requests.

Comment: I would tell whatever is master is final `(D,E)`, if merging the feature is into master which means `(A,B,C)` this should be absolutely fine. Any reason why you want to exclude the `(D,E)`? One more question is: Did you branch off `feature` after `D,E` on `master` or before?

Comment: `feature` branched off `master` before `D,E` @ArunG  -> these commits are seen in the merge request commits and change log. `D,E` are commits merged into master separately from `feature`

Comment: @ArunG -> `D,E` are separately merged into `master`. Unrelated to `feature`

Comment: As master has two new commits. You can not perform fast forward merge until you `rebase` the `feature` on top of `master`. Right now this will be a `three way merge`. when you `rebase` `feature` with `master` it will perform `fast forward merge`.

Answer (score 0):

If your current merge request does not suit you, you can override it with the same `feature` branch, replayed on top of the latest `master` state:

```
git checkout feature
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git push --force
```

You should then have an updated merge request which, this time, should only include commits from `feature` branch.